# Inactive control panel buttons

Tags: administrator, menu-item, weblinks

I moved my site to the other host and got a troubles in administration panel.
Top menu is inactive, any button does not work.

The other problem - I can not update my version 3.8.6 to 3.8.7. The package gets to the tmp  directory and progress bar are shown but nothing else.

What I have did:

-$log_path and  $tmp_path are tuned

-Rights on directories and files are 755 and 644(media, images, tmp, cache...777).

-Files and database was removed few times but problems are not dissapeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using local web server where my website could work properly.I had updated joomla packages to 3.8.8 and transfer them to host and done some work with my extensions.

Comment: Please award your answer the green tick to prevent the system from "bumping" your question for new attention.